# How to obscure Database password?

Tags: java, jpa, passwords, persistence, embedded-database

I am using **JPA2.0** (*Eclipselink*) to interact with DB and I have `persistence.xml` file which has some DB configuration. I want to obscure the password used for accessing DB. I am using eclipse IDE. The following config tags are used in `persistence.xml` file.

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="app"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
```

I don't want to mention the password here in `xml`.  How do I go about it?

Note: My application is composed of Swing with Apache's Derby **Embedded** DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let the *server* store the password and then you can retrieve it using [`JNDI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/).

It would also be possible to encrypt the password, and decrypt in the client. Although this would be susceptible to dictionary attacks, or even straight out reversing the process by decompiling your program.

Comment: if OP's application will run in an application server, or above any jndi provider, your answer is the right way to go.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I forgot to mention that I am using embedded DB.

Comment: @Ahamed, then I don't *really* see a way. You can obscure it a bit by setting it statically in your class file, encrypted or not.

Answer (score 0):

What typically happens in this scenario is you store the hash in the XML file and on the backend you validate that the hashes match.

You should be able to do something like the following pseudocode:

```
String password = property.getParam(password);  
String user = property.getParam(user);  

function validateHash(String unhashedPassword, String unhashedUser)  
{  
    String passHash = generateMD5(unhashedPassword);  
    String userHash = generateMD5(unhashedUser);  

    if(!password.equals(passHash) && !user.equals(userHash)  
    {  
       throw new SecurityException("Oh noez hackstar");  
    }  
}
```

The discussion around which hashing algorithm to use is a lengthy one, there is nothing that bad about MD5 as long as you aren't trying to protect nuclear launch codes.

Comment: Sure, but usually not when you're trying to *connect* to the database.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Actually it works just fine when connecting to the database. You do store hashed credentials dont you, therefore this process is fine. If you are storing plaintext passwords please change that right away. Essentially the database doesn't care.  Especially if my username is cat and my password happens to be an MD5 hash of my password of 'awesome'

Comment: indeed. But what I meant was that the plain-text password must then be stored as a String in the program, which is equally unsafe, albeit obscured a bit.

Comment: Correct it does have to be somewhere at the end of the day.  Whether that be from user input at start up or somewhere else.